# having problems in python retrieving a response with resquests

Tags: python, request, python-requests

So earlier today I had some code that worked fine and now all of a sudden it doesn't. As a disclaimer I ran the code approximately 1000 times on the site for about 5hrs straight so maybe that's why I'm having issues.

Here's what I've tried and what was working earlier today.

```
import requests

payload = {'l': 'MyEmail', 'd': 'MyPass', 'login_ok': '1', 'do': 'Sign In'}
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post('http://www.marketinout.com/home/login.php', data=payload)

#to confirm it's working since watchlists can only be accesed once logged in

r = s.get('http://www.marketinout.com/wl/my_watch_lists.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup)
```

It was working great ealier today like I said but now it sometimes gives me nothing, sometimes b'', sometimes

```
<!--INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/signals/init.php"-->
```

No clue what's going on.

Comment: Maybe the server has detected your unusual request. So it'll try to reject your request. Most of the famous sites have a bot-detection stuffs to detect the unusual requests, mostly by crawlers.

Comment: Should I email the site and ask? I was only automating a process. I tested all possible combinations of the 7 day moving average against the 50 day average times a percentage. It was something like 1225 requests.

Comment: checking out http://www.marketinout.com/robots.txt are these some of the pages you were trying to scrape? If all you want to do is compare moving averages, python has a yahoo-finance module that you can pull prices for each day and just compute it https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance/1.3.2

Comment: No so what the site does it check a formula vs historical stock data and tests how much you would have made. I input a formula, ran the backtest, gathered data and then ran it again. 1300 times. Yahoo finance doesn't have a backtest option for a specific formula.